# VB Downscaling coordinates

Tags: vb.net, line, gdi+, contains

I have the need to know when a gdi+ drawn line is clicked on by the mouse.

I have fashioned this function which is used in a loop on all the existing lines and what the function does is:

1. It makes a buffer of the line's container's size
2. It makes the whole thing black
3. It draws the line in green
4. It gets the pixel at the mouse location
5. If the pixel is different from black a.k.a green, the line has successfully been clicked and the function should then return true.

This works great, there's no misinterpretations, but I'm afraid that there's a tiny delay (not really noticeable) when my form is in full screen (due to the large buffer).

I'm looking for a way to optimize this, and my first thought is to downscale everything. So what I mean by that is make the buffer like 20x20 and then draw the line in a scaled down version using math. Problem is, I suck at math, so I'm basically asking you how to do this and preferably with an explanation for dummies.

This is the function:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal e As Point) As Boolean
    Dim Width As Integer = Container.Size.Width
    Dim Height As Integer = Container.Size.Height

    Dim Buffer As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Buffer)
        G.Clear(Color.Black)

        Dim Start As Point = New Point(ParentNode.Location.X + ParentNode.Size.Width / 2, ParentNode.Location.Y + ParentNode.Size.Height / 2)
        Dim [End] As Point = New Point(ChildNode.Location.X + ChildNode.Size.Width / 2, ChildNode.Location.Y + ChildNode.Size.Height / 2)

        Dim Control1 As Point
        Dim Control2 As Point
        Control1.X = Start.X + GetAngle(ChildNode.Location, ParentNode.Location, ChildNode.Location.X - ParentNode.Location.X, ChildNode.Location.Y - ParentNode.Location.Y)
        Control1.Y = Start.Y

        Control2.X = [End].X
        Control2.Y = Start.Y

        G.DrawBezier(New Pen(Color.Green, 4), Start, Control1, Control2, [End])
    End Using

    If Buffer.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb() <> Color.Black.ToArgb() Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

This is one of my attempts to make the function use the idea above:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal e As Point) As Boolean
    Dim Width As Integer = 20
    Dim Height As Integer = 20

    Dim Buffer As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Buffer)
    G.Clear(Color.Black)

    Dim Start As Point = New Point(ParentNode.Location.X + ParentNode.Size.Width / 2, ParentNode.Location.Y + ParentNode.Size.Height / 2)
    Dim [End] As Point = New Point(ChildNode.Location.X + ChildNode.Size.Width / 2, ChildNode.Location.Y + ChildNode.Size.Height / 2)

    Dim Control1 As Point
    Dim Control2 As Point
    Control1.X = Start.X + GetAngle(ChildNode.Location, ParentNode.Location, ChildNode.Location.X - ParentNode.Location.X, ChildNode.Location.Y - ParentNode.Location.Y)
    Control1.Y = Start.Y

    Control2.X = [End].X
    Control2.Y = Start.Y

    G.DrawBezier(New Pen(Color.Green, 4), New Point(Start.X / Width, Start.Y / Height), New Point(Control1.X / Width, Control1.Height / Height), New Point(Control2.X / Width, Control2.Y / Height), New Point([End].X / Width, [End].Y / Height))
End Using

If Buffer.GetPixel(Width, Height).ToArgb() <> Color.Black.ToArgb() Then
    Return True
End If

Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx) for drawing and testing with the built-in [IsOutlineVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isoutlinevisible(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal e As Point) As Boolean
  Dim result as Boolean = False
  Using gp As New GraphicsPath
    gp.AddBezier(your four points)
    Using p As New Pen(Color.Empty, 4)
      result = gp.IsOutlineVisible(e, p)
    End Using
  End Using
  Return result
End Function
```

Side note: Bitmaps and Graphic objects need to be disposed when you create them.

Comment: That is gold! Thanks dude! - I had no idea that one also need to dispose of graphics objects like Pen, SolidBrush, etc. I thought that disposing off the graphics object would suffice.